# How to encrypt LDAP password using SHA-256

Tags: java, ldap, sha

I am working on java web application where i need to authenticate user's password

using LDAP server i am not too much aware with this.My request from application server to LDAP is

already encrypted with certificate file but i still need to encrypt password using SHA-256.

how can i do ???

**My Java code is :**

```
            Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldaps://" + ldap_url);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, auth_method);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "abcd123"+"@"+ldap_domain);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mypassword");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystorePath);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

I got this [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/digest.html) but unable to do with SHA-256

Comment: Generally, we would expect your LDAP server will encrypt the password. You just need to send itn in text over SSL. (or using StartTLS)

Comment: Yeah, but I m talking about encryption of information flowing over the network, Can i do ?? like this link is doing with MD5 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/digest.html

Comment: SHA-256 is not an encryption algorithm. You don't need to do any pre-processing on LDAP passwords yourself. The LDAP server will do whatever is necessary. All you need to provide is a secure transport. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we would expect your LDAP server will encrypt the password. You just need to send itn in text over SSL. (or using StartTLS)

If you are using SSL, then you are encrypted. Otherwise you would need to use something like [SASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) which requires support on the client and the server.

-jim